# How can I calculate if a user is in time? (How does NOW() work?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I know there's a lot of tutorials and stuff about this kind of things, but I have searched and based in what I watched [here](https://es.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3978-excel-if-time-is-greater-than.html) and [here](https://ideasdeexcel.blogspot.com/2018/05/condicional-si-con-horas-funcion-valor.html) (sorry if both are in spanish).
I want to now, using the hour of `now()` (in cell `B3`) if `B3` is in the range of 8:00:00 (`A2`) and 13:00:00 (`B2`)

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | ENTRY | EXIT | In time? |
| **2** | 8:00:00 | 13:00:00 | ***FORMULA*** |
| **3** | Actual time: | 8:40 |  |

Using what I saw on the internet, I'm using this formula in `c2`:

```
=if(and(value(B3)=>(value(A2)),(value(B3))<=(value(B2))),"In time","Not in time")
```

As you can see, my time is 8:40:00, so it is between 8:00:00 and 13:00:00, I would like some help to know what am I doing wrong (maybe it is just a fool issue but I'm not very good at excel) because, depending on the blogs I watched, it should work and show "In time" in `c2` and it is showing "Not in time".

And I would like to do it with `now()`, because, when I hardcoded the hour by simply just typing "8:40:00", it works.

EDIT: All cells are in format "Hour".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it, [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/23/excel-time-format-now-time-functions/) it says I have to convert it to the nearest int, so in `b3` I changed this:

```
= now()
```

to this:

```
= now()-int(now())
```

Added more details:

I changed because the `now()` function changes only the display format, but the value in the cell is still a decimal number.
By adding `int()`, this takes the decimal value of `now()` and converts it into the nearest integer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The now() function will include a date by default. In cell B3, change your formula to this:

```
    =TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))
```

This will extract only the time from the current now datetime.

Comment: Thank you mate, i didn't know this!